# filling rows with conditions in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, rowdatabound

I need to evaluate a condition from a database using linq so that a checkbox for each row enables or no, I think it can be done using the `RowDataBound` or `CreateRow` event.

i.e, I have a gridview with several columns that are fillied with a datasource from linq. Out of all those columns two of them have each a checkbox, so if a record from the base is equal to one, only column2 with the checkbox for that row is enabled, if it's not equal to one, then it stays as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared you simplified sample how this can be done using databinding.

First aspx code, take notice I have used ValidateRecord to validate single record:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled='<%# ValidateRecord(Eval("RowState")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItems" TypeName="WebTester.DataGridTester">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

End now the code behind. GetItems is used only to generate some demo data, the point is inside ValidateRecord:

```
    public bool ValidateRecord(object value)
    { 
        return (value as int?) == 1;
    }

    public static DataTable GetItems()
    { 
        //generate some demo data...
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("RowState", typeof(int?));
        dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col6", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col7", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 1,"some","data","in","first","row", ".", ".." });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 2, "second", "record", "inside", "demo", "datatable", "-", "--" });
        return dt;
    }
```

So final result will look something like this:
[image]

First row checkbox is enabled, second is disabled.

Happy coding!